# How to change MYSQL Database columns filed Collation

Tags: mysql

I need to change below collation to **utf8_general_ci**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Alter` table clause

```
ALTER TABLE `change_messages` CHANGE `message` `message` TEXT CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```